# add header to stdout stream in single-line bash pipeline

Tags: bash

I'm trying to add a header to a `stdout` stream. The best I could come up with is the following, using a temp file and `cat`'s hyphen option. How can I turn this into a one-liner pipeline? Thanks.

```
python myscript.py myparm > tmp
echo 'a,b,c' | cat - tmp  > output
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No temp file or unnecessary `cat` needed:

```
{ echo 'a,b,c'; python myscript.py myparm; } > output
```

Note that both the spaces around the curly braces and the trailing `;` are required.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
echo 'a,b,c' | cat - <(python myscript.py myparm)  > output
```

or:

```
cat <(echo 'a,b,c') <(python myscript.py myparm)  > output
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the method I use to pipe data through gzip in cgi scripts.  Everything in the while loop goes through the output unless you specifically redirect it inside the loop (This can be pretty useful).

```
RUNONCE=""
while ([ ! "$RUNONCE" ]) do
  RUNONCE=true
  echo stuff
  exec stuff
  cat stuff
  #whatever you want
done >output
```

Comment: I don't see the benefit of this approach over using a simple command group.

Comment: @chepner For this example there isn't one, but it can be adapted for additional future needs.  If I knew it was never going to change I would just use John's method.

Answer (score -1):

None of the solutions above worked for my case.
But, something similar to the accepted solution worked:

```
(echo "a,b,c" && my-command)
```

for example:

```bash
(echo "a,b,c" && seq 3) | tee new.log
```

```bash
cat new.log
```

```
a,b,c
1
2
3
```

Comment: Why didn't the accepted solution work? Make sure to include the spaces around the curly braces as well as the trailing semicolon: `{ echo "a,b,c"; my-command; }`.

Comment: Downvote for adding a needlessly inefficient answer (using `( )` instead of `{ }` tells the shell to `fork()` off a subprocess, so there's an actual performance penalty here). And double-check your spacing and presence of command separators; John K's explanation is indeed the biggest mistake folks make using grouping syntax (since `{` and `}` are able to be passed as arguments -- notice how `echo { hi }` works whereas `echo ( hi )` throws a syntax error).